# the element background color missed for css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going to set the width of element.
the element will wrap any text within it
but if you set the div tag width to smaller than some element within the div tag that cannot wrap, the div tag will not get any smaller than that element
basically, it should work like a normal html element
it should allow setting the width, as long as the width is not less than something that will not wrap

http://jsbin.com/taxawopace/1/edit?html,output
check it, please
the background color missed as you can see.
how do i have to do?
thanks

**HTML/CSS:**

```
  <div class="map-data-dialog" id="map-data-dialog" style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 111111; border-color: rgb(23, 56, 14); width: 40px; color: rgb(1, 1, 1); left: 10px; top: 10px; background: rgb(218, 218, 218); padding: 12px;">
    <div class="map-data-box clearfix" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 18.3px; font-weight: 600; min-width: 40px;">
        <h3 class="map-title" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 18.3px; font-weight: 600;">test</h3>
        <div class="map-content" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 18.3px; font-weight: 600;"><div style="color: red; font-weight: 600; font-size: 18.3px; font-family: arial;">for testing method</div><p style="font-family: arial; font-size: 18.3px; font-weight: 600;">this is easy listenning for business</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please separate your css from your html in the future please.

Comment: Do you mean `word-break:break-all;`? Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fofogepiqo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Specify image representation for expected output if you don't want to break the word..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/taxawopace/1/edit?html,output

Comment: i only have to change the background color area

Comment: when we set the width 50 px, if the width of any word is bigger 50px (ex: the width is 70px), the box's width has to be 70px.

Answer (score 0):

Add `word-break:break-all;` to the div map-data-box, so that the text will break down to fit in the div.

Comment: i am sorry it is not what i mean.

Comment: the word has not to break out.

Comment: The word will break because the parent div doesn't have enough width.

Comment: the word like http://jsbin.com/taxawopace/1/edit?html,output     the background color area has to be changed

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not getting what you mean.

Comment: when we set the width 50 px, if the width of any word is bigger 50px (ex: the width is 70px), the box's width has to be 70px.

Comment: So you mean when the width of the word increases the parent container's width should also increase? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you want that the div will wrap the text inside it you should change

```
display: block;
```

with

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: when we set the width 50 px, if the width of any word is bigger 50px (ex: the width is 70px), the box's width has to be 70px.

Answer (score 0):

try like this: **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/rigoqeqenu/1/)**

```
 <div class="map-data-dialog" id="map-data-dialog" style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 111111; border-color: rgb(23, 56, 14); width: 40px; color: rgb(1, 1, 1); left: 10px; top: 10px; background: rgb(218, 218, 218); padding: 12px; word-wrap: break-word;">
```

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` in `map-data-dialog` div

Comment: in that case, the word is broken out. but the word has not to be broken out like jsbin.com/fofogepiqo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: when we set the width 50 px, if the width of any word is bigger 50px (ex: the width is 70px), the box's width has to be 70px.